# Unable to figure out the usage

Tags: java-8, lambda

Following is one of the exercises from Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient.

> Form a subclass Collection2 from Collection and add a default method
>   void forEachIf(Consumer action, Predicate filter) that applies
>   action to each element for which filter returns true. How could you
>   use it?

Following is my definition of `Collection2`. I am unable to figure out how to use it.

```
public interface Collection2<E> extends Collection<E>
{

    default void forEachIf(Consumer<E> action, Predicate<E> filter)
    {
        forEach(e -> {
            if (filter.test(e))
            {
                action.accept(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, I have the following list that i would like to apply the `String.toUpperCase` action for the strings that start with "a". How would I use `Collection2` to achieve that?

```
public static void ex09()
{
        Collection<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("abc");
        l.add("zxx");
        l.add("axc");

        // What next???

}
```

Comment: Composition over inheritance. Why extend `Collection`? I believe already [Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) cover good number of similar use cases.

Comment: because the assignment said to extend Collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a new class that implements `Collection2`,

```
public class ArrayList2<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Collection2<E>{

}
```

then just use your new class:

```
public static void ex09()
{
    Collection2<String> l = new ArrayList2<>();
    l.add("abc");
    l.add("zxx");
    l.add("axc");

    l.forEachIf(  (s)->System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()),
                  (s)-> s.startsWith("a"));


}
```

Which when run will print:

```
ABC
AXC
```